# The method 'Column' isn't defined for the type '_NoticeViewState'

Tags: flutter, dart

Errors occur in basic Flutter widgets and functions.

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` has been written.

An error occurs in "ALL" dart files.

- Error

> The method 'Column' isn't defined for the type '_NoticeViewState'. (Documentation)
>
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Column'.

- Doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.8, on macOS 13.6.3 22G436 darwin-x64, locale ko-KR)
    • Flutter version 3.16.8 on channel stable at /Users/user/Documents/libraries.nosync/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 67457e669f (2days ago), 2024-01-16 16:22:29 -0800
    • Engine revision 6e2ea58a5c
    • Dart version 3.2.5
    • DevTools version 2.28.5

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 33.0.0-rc3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15C500b
    • CocoaPods version 1.14.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.80.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    ...

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

[image]

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:project1/common/components/organisms/BottomNavigationBar/custom_bottom_navigation_bar.item.dart';

import '../../../../notice/provider/notice_provider.dart';
import '../../../theme/color/theme_color.dart';
import '../../../theme/typo/typo.dart';

class CustomBottomNavigationBar extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CustomBottomNavigationBar({
    super.key,
    required this.items,
  });

  final List<CustomBottomNavigationBarItem> items;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final noticeBadge = ref.watch(noticeBadgeCountProvider);
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      minimum: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: Platform.isIOS ? 25 : 16),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          if (noticeBadge > 0)
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: BasicColor(context).primary,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 20),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'New news has been posted.'.tr(),
                style: Typo.labelM.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: items,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

- pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: name
description: description
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.10.0+60

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  easy_localization: ^3.0.2
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.2
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  loading_animation_widget: ^1.2.0+4
  figma_squircle: ^0.5.3
  go_router: ^12.0.0
  riverpod_annotation: ^2.3.0
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.6
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  retrofit: ^4.0.1
  logger: ^2.0.2
  dio: ^5.3.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.1.0
  crypto: ^3.0.3
  intl: ^0.18.1
  debounce_throttle: ^2.0.0
  sliver_tools: ^0.2.12
  package_info_plus: ^5.0.1
  local_auth: ^2.1.7
  another_flushbar: ^1.12.30
  permission_handler: ^11.0.1
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  webview_flutter: ^4.4.2
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  mobile_scanner: ^3.5.5
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  camera: ^0.10.5+7
  path_drawing: ^1.0.1
  native_exif: ^0.5.0
  native_device_orientation: ^1.2.1
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  flutter_barometer: ^0.1.0
  geolocator: ^10.1.0
  device_info_plus: ^9.1.1
  flutter_compass: ^0.8.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^16.3.0
  url_launcher: ^6.2.3



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  custom_lint: ^0.5.3
  riverpod_lint: ^2.3.4
  riverpod_generator: ^2.3.6
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
  retrofit_generator: ^7.0.8
  hive_generator: ^2.0.1


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/icons/flags/
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/translations/
    - env/
  fonts:
    - family: Pretendard
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Pretendard-Medium.otf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Pretendard-SemiBold.otf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Pretendard-Bold.otf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Pretendard-ExtraBold.otf
          weight: 800
```

Comment: can you share your import section

Comment: read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh
I added screenshots and code to make it easier to check.
This error does not occur in a single file, but in all dart files in the project.

Comment: @Qori
I added screenshots and code to make it easier to check. This error does not occur in a single file, but in all dart files in the project.

Comment: If you create a new Dart file, import **only** `package:flutter/material.dart`, add a simple `StatelessWidget` with some `Column` and `EdgeInsets`, does the error still happen?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan
The error still occurs.

Comment: Please include your `pubspec.yaml` then, the problem could be there

Comment: @DhafinRayhan
Done. Please review.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan
The same problem is occurring in other projects as well.
Flutter downgrade and upgrade didn't work.

Comment: Could be an IDE related problem. Have you tried in other IDE?

Comment: I restarted the laptop several times as well as the IDE but it didn't work.

Comment: It looks like you have both Android Studio and VSCode. Does the error happen on both?

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get` ?